# ```TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'bool'``` when trying to add data to my database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been working with Django for a while now whenever I apply this BaseModel:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    is_active = models.BinaryField(default = True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

to any model for example:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

and when I make migrations and migrate everything works fine and migrates go through and then I registered my models to admin site to add some data to check if my models are working and whenever I hit save to add new data I'm getting this error:

```
nternal Server Error: /admin/ass/ass/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 715, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 188, in _view_wrapper
    result = _process_exception(request, e)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 186, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 80, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 240, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1944, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 188, in _view_wrapper
    result = _process_exception(request, e)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 186, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1803, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1854, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1258, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 822, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 909, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1067, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1108, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1847, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1745, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
                 ^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1746, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1747, in <listcomp>
    self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1686, in prepare_value
    return field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1013, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\CORE\React\CinemaReservationSystem\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2701, in get_db_prep_value
    return connection.Database.Binary(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'bool'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be an issue with the `is_active` field in your `BaseModel`. The `BinaryField` is expecting a bytes-like object, but it's receiving a boolean value (`True`).

You might want to consider using a `BooleanField` instead for the `is_active` field in your `BaseModel`.

```
from django.db import models
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at =
models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at =

models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
    abstract = True
class MyModel(BaseModel):
text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```